# Can "run-through" be a noun?

Tags: phrases, nouns, hyphenation

Is it possible for "run-through" to be a noun? If so, please give an example sentence containing this noun. Also, please describe a situation in which the sentence would naturally be used.

Please note that I'm not asking about cases in which "run-through" would act more like a modifier ("He chose a run-through mode for his system", "There is a need for a run-through program", "Another run-through strategy will ruin the whole project", etc.).

Comment: Any word can possibly be a noun in English. Whether it gets used in that way more than a handful of times is a different question, and generally unpredictable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> We were all off book so we did a run-through of the entire script.

This is an acting term. A "run-through" is a preliminary practice performance of a play, done complete without interruption.

Note: "off book" means an actor has his/her lines committed to memory.

Comment: It’s also used in various other performing contexts besides acting: I’m familiar with it from music (“In our last rehearsal, we will do a complete run-through of the symphony.”) and from talks/lectures (“I was a bit nervous about my conference talk, so I did an extra run-through in my hotel room the night before.”)

Answer (score 3):

> The night before her big speech, Carla gave it one last run-through.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add my two cents, it can also be used in the context of performing a practice drill, as in: "We did a run-through of the code blue response and our times were terrible."